# Regular parametrization of a surface is conformal iff it preserves angles.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, conformal-geometry, parametrization

Can anyone give me some hints of how to start the proof, because I have no idea where to start.

I know if a parametrization is conformal, then $E=G$ and $F=0$, where E,F,G are values in the first fundamental form $I=Edu^2+2Fdudv+Gdv^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The cosine of the angle between two vectors $u,v$ with respect to an inner product $\cdot$ is $$\frac{u \cdot v}{\sqrt{(u\cdot u) (v\cdot v)}}.$$ In the parameter domain you have the standard dot product, and in the surface geometry you have $u \cdot v=u^T I v$. Show that when $I$ has the form you are assuming, these two inner products produce the same angle cosine.

Comment: What about the other direction. When the parametrisation preserves angeles, then it is conformal.

Comment: @zermelovac: choosing $u,v$ to be the two coordinate basis vectors and applying the preservation of angle cosine shows $F=0$. Another judicious choice of vectors will let you show $E=G$.